# Calling a segue in one class from another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uialertview, segue

I have a `UIViewController` that calls a method on a singleton object in which, given a certain condition, displays a `UIAlertView`. When the user taps the button in the `UIAlertView` I want the `UIAlertView` to disappear (which at the moment it does) and then the `UIViewController` behind it to segue to another scene. My problem is that the `UIAlertView` is from the singleton class, while the segue needs to be performed on the `UIViewController`.

In `Singleton.m`:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Button!"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Segue!" sender: self];
    }
}
```

My question is what do i replace `self` with that will allow me to notify the `UIViewController` that it's time to do a segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Notify' is a good word.  :)  I suggest having the view controller listen for a NSNotification that the singleton will post when it wants the segue to happen.  Then the `perform...` code would move into the view controller method that's called in response to the notification.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I was completely unfamiliar with `NSNotification`s, so I just looked up a quick tutorial on how to use them, and your idea worked! Thanks again :D